# Which amiibo will Uncle Amiibo recognize by name?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey, amiibo

In Super Mario Odyssey, there are certain amiibo that Uncle Amiibo will recognize by name when scanned.

For example: Uncle Amiibo specifically referred to my Waluigi, Shulk, and Isabelle amiibo [by name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay7Ah.jpg), while my Shovel Knight and Pac Man figures were referred to as [*lovely* amiibo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e17ym.jpg).

**Which amiibo will Uncle Amiibo recognize by name? Which ones will he call *lovely* amiibo?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty exhaustive list found on [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/200275-super-mario-odyssey/75930458/889355818):

> **Super Mario**
>
> - Mario
> - Dr. Mario
> - Mario (Wedding)
> - Luigi
> - Peach
> - Peach (Wedding)
> - Yoshi
> - Yarn Yoshi
> - Rosalina
> - Rosalina and Luma
> - Bowser (non Skylander)
> - Bowser Wedding
> - Bowser Jr.
> - Wario
> - Donkey Kong (non Skylander)
> - Diddy Kong
> - Toad
> - Daisy
> - Waluigi
> - Boo
> - Poochy
> - Yarn Poochy
>
> **Legend of Zelda**
>
> - Link
> - Zelda
> - Ganon
> - Ganondorf
> - Wolf Link
> - Guardian
> - Bokoblin
>
> **Animal Crossing**
>
> - Villager
> - Isabelle
> - Isabelle Winter
> - K.K.
> - Tom Nook
> - Timmy & Tommy
> - Mabel
> - Reese
> - Cyrus
> - Digby
> - Rover
> - Resetti
> - Blathers
> - Celeste
> - Kicks
> - Kapp'n
> - Lottie
>
> **Star Fox**
>
> - Fox
> - Falco
>
> **Metroid**
>
> - Samus
> - Zero Suit Samus
>
> **Kid Icarus**
>
> - Pit
> - Dark Pit
> - Palutena
>
> **Retro**
>
> - Mr. Game & Watch
> - R.O.B.
> - Duck Hunt
>
> **Miis**
>
> - Mii
> - Mii Gunner
> - Mii Swordfighter
> - Mii Brawler
>
> **Splatoon**
>
> - Inkling
> - Inkling Boy
> - Inkling Girl
> - Inkling Squid
> - Callie
> - Marie
>
> **Pokemon**
>
> - Charizard
> - Pikachu
> - Jigglypuff
> - Mewtwo
> - Lucario
> - Greninja
>
> **H.A.L Laboratory**
>
> - Kirby
> - Meta Knight
> - King Dedede
> - Waddle Dee
> - Qbby
>
> **Fire Emblem**
>
> - Marth
> - Ike
> - Lucina
> - Robin
> - Roy
> - Alm
> - Celica
>
> **Mother**
>
> - Ness
> - Lucas
>
> **Misc**.
>
> - Captain Falcon
> - Olimar
> - Little Mac
> - Wii Fit Trainer
> - Shulk
> - Chibi-Robo
>
> amiibo not listed here will simply be called "lovely" or "cool" by Uncle amiibo.

Comment: Note: Someone pointed out on the site that a "Ganon" Amiibo does not exist.

Comment: someone later said that the reason there's an "inkling" is because of how Amiibo IDs work, so if an Inkling Baby is released it will be called "Inkling".  then he said "Ganon is a variant of Ganondorf" for presumably the same reason, if a Ganon Amiibo is released it will still be named